# Android How to add a custom xml file in res/values and how to register the customvalues.xml with the system

Tags: android

I want to add a custom xml which having URLs to the res/values folder. I can add the file but how to read its content by getResources() ?

Comment: Can't you put the URLs in strings.xml?

Comment: well possible but not nice um only keeping the component related things inside the strings.xml and I do not want to complicate it by adding URLs (external addresses)

Comment: Well :) ya its possible but I prefer to go with res/values/url.xml like that. Thank you

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Update:** This doesn't seem to work anymore (but it used to) and you cannot create your own custom types in android. Only the [standard available resource types work now](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html).

Therefore, the only way to achieve something like this would be, have your separate file as suggested, **url.xml** and have all yours URLs in that file so that it doesn't get mixed up with the other Strings. It just improves readability and maintainability, AFAIK.

The URL item now looks like,

```
<item name="myUrl" type="string">http://myUrl.com</item>
```

And you needs to be accessed the usual way:

```
String myurl = getResources().getString(R.string.myUrl);
```

---

**Original Answer:**

Try something like this:-

**url.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="myUrl" type="urls">http://myUrl.com</item>
</resources>
```

And in your activity, get it like this:-

```
String s = getResources().getString(R.urls.myUrl);
```

**Note:-** You needn't register your `xml` anywhere. Just make sure its available in `res/values` folder.

**Snapshot:-**

[image: How I used]

Comment: R.urls well I cannot access urls via R can you please look at it?

Comment: It did work for me. I ran the code in an emulator and only then posted it here. Be double sure about the `type` in `item` you are using. Also, try to clean and build your code again.

Comment: Okay Thank you . though not works for me . The static class url did not get created in the R.java

Comment: @MarcoJohannesen as far as I can remember when adding the file select as a resource xml and do the configuration in the file and you can access those values via @ String reference .

Comment: @Kalanamith ... thanks, did that and tried doing "Clean" and it worked! Thanks :D

Comment: For me - this solution works only with standard types (string/integer etc.) but not with custom like 'url'.

Comment: type="urls" ? is this new? <Made by R.J>

Comment: This example is wrong. You can make res/values/foo.xml, but you still reference the values inside via the type of the resource. E.g., R.string.*, etc.  string.xml is just  convention, you can put any file in the values/ folder you want. Android processes all of them and makes the resources therein available via R.*.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman - Isn't that what I've done here? The type here in the example I've given is `type="urls"` and therefore, I'm accessing it using `R.urls.*`. When I had written this answer, it was working fine. Not sure if newer versions of android make a meal of it. I'll check that and see if what I've posted works or not.

Comment: you can't do `R.urls.*`, that doesn't work. you can put a string (or whatever) in `res/urls.xml`, and reference it as `R.string.*`.

Comment: I have just come upon this change. Why does this not work anymore? Anyone know when this was taken out? I have just "upgraded" from Eclipse ADT to Android Studio and the custom types (like "configuration" which I could access via R.configuration) no longer work.

Answer (score 6):

1. Create your custom xml file, ensure it is in res folder (I've tested this by putting it in res/values folder)
2. Ensure all the values you place in this XML are of a [standard type](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html).
3. You can then use the corresponding R call. For example for integer you do R.integer.YOUR_CUSTOM_XML_VALUE. Doesn't matter which xml this integer is located in, it will be registered by R as long as it is in res folder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have a custom file: I just did this a couple of times.
1) Make a new xml file.
2) Use file format as as wrapper for yours
Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <item name="languages">
        <languages>
            <language>
                <isocode>
                    en-UK
                </isocode>
                <name>
                    English (UK)
                </name>
            </language>
        </languages>
    </item>
</resources>
```

Comment: Also you can put it in the string tag as a giant string: Of course custom parsing is required in any case.