# How google analytics library reads values in analytics.xml without access to R package?

Tags: android, android-resources, android-library

Google provides libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar which can be initialized by calling

`gaTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(context);`

In that case values needed for initialization (trackingId) are read from analytics.xml. I want  add that ability to my library project. But reading the values requires having access to compiled R. class.

`String s = getResources().getString(R.urls.myUrl);`

as explained in this answer:
[Android How to add a custom xml file in res/values and how to register the customvalues.xml with the system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152933/android-how-to-add-a-custom-xml-file-in-res-values-and-how-to-register-the-custo)

Is there a way to read the values using only the name of the value? I can not add a dependency on the main project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they could did it like this:

```
String packageName = context.getPackageName();
int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("ga_trackingId", "string", packageName);
String val = context.getString(resId);
Log.d("String From Res", val);
```