# How to set dynamic font sizes for Xamarin portable project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am very beginner for Xamarin Environment.

I have develop the portable project using Xamarin forms & it works fine in multi-platforms (Android,IOS,windows)

**My problem:**

In android it have multiple devices so they maintain different dimension folder structure for multi-device management.

**For example:**

- values
- values-sw320dp
- values-sw600dp
- values-sw720dp

**My Xamarin Form code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MultiDeviceDemo"
         x:Class="MultiDeviceDemo.MainPage">

<!--currently fontsize hardcoded.. How to replace this to dyanamic-->
<Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
       VerticalOptions="Center"
       HorizontalOptions="Center" 
     FontSize="30"/>

</ContentPage>
```

**My question:**

In my above

> FontSize="30"

was hard-coded.. I want to replace this to value to android dimension structure.

How to set dynamic font sizes for label?

Comment: You could use platform idiom `<OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double"          Phone="20" Tablet="40"/>` or manage font size from code.

Comment: I really thank to @EgorGromadskiy.. I searched in google without single clue.. You give the clue.. If possible you post as answer.. I ready to accept this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use platform idiom:

```
<Label>
  <Label.FontSize>
    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
             Phone="20"
             Tablet="40"/>
  </Label.FontSize>
</Label>
```

Comment: This answer suit for IOS application. But In android it have various devices.. So I want to access the dimension values from **dimens.xml** Could you help me??

Comment: @RanjithKumar [how to use custom files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152933/android-how-to-add-a-custom-xml-file-in-res-values-and-how-to-register-the-custo). Could you tell me what do you have in **dimens.xml**?

Comment: I have different font-sizes for supporting multi-device support in android.. **values-sw-320dp,values-sw-600dp,values-sw-720dp,etc**