# How to show coordinates-markers on Android App with Google Maps from XML file

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

I have an xml file with some places in it and their coordinates. I want to show those places on my android app on Google Maps as markers. I have already load the maps. 
How could I do this? Any help would be so much appreciated, even if someone could explain it theoritically, as it seems I cant grasp its concept. Can someone help?

example of xml file(placesp.xml):

```
<placesp>
<placep>
  <place_id>1</place_id>
  <name>Place1</name>
  <description>Place description 1</description>
  <coordinates>;40.430224;21.559570</coordinates>
</placep>
<placep>
  <place_id>2</place_id>
  <name>Place2</name>
  <description>Place description 2</description>
  <coordinates>;40.423324;21.062439</coordinates>
</placep>
<placep>
  <place_id>3</place_id>
  <name>Place3</name>
  <description>Place description 3</description>
  <coordinates>;40.266952;21.238220</coordinates>
</placep>
</placesp>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a HashMap to save the data.
You just create a new class like this:

```
public class Coordinates {
public static final HashMap<String, LatLng> COORDINATES = new HashMap<String, LatLng>();
static {

    // Place1
    COORDINATES.put("Place1", new LatLng(40.430224;21.559570));
}
```

}

You can access the data stored by the hashmap like this:

```
                locationLatLng = new LatLng(Coordinates.COORDINATES.get("Place1").latitude,Coordinates.COORDINATES.get("Place1").longitude);
```

And then using this line in the class where you loaded the map to add the markers:

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(locationLatLng));
```

I am not really sure how to access data from the xml file, but in theory the logic is the same. You have to get a LatLng coordinate to tell the addMarker method where to put the marker, and thats actually it. I hope I could help you with this.

Comment: hello thanks for the answer! Is there anyway to get the info of the places from the xml file? So if I the content is changed the markes on map would change too?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html check this out. There is a default strings.xml file in the values folder, which can be accessed in the code by getString(R.string.NAME)...Perhaps you can put your coordinates in strings and then cast them to LatLng. Apparently you cannot access data of a custom xml file according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152933/android-how-to-add-a-custom-xml-file-in-res-values-and-how-to-register-the-custo

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a model class to hold the information for each place. I provide you a sample bellow: **Place.class**

```
public class Place {
private int placeId;
private String placeName;
private String placeDescription;
private double placeLongitude;
private double placeLatitude;

public Place() {
    super();
}

public int getPlaceId() {
    return placeId;
}

public void setPlaceId(final int placeId) {
    this.placeId = placeId;
}

public String getPlaceName() {
    return placeName;
}

public void setPlaceName(final String placeName) {
    this.placeName = placeName;
}

public String getPlaceDescription() {
    return placeDescription;
}

public void setPlaceDescription(final String placeDescription) {
    this.placeDescription = placeDescription;
}

public double getPlaceLongitude() {
    return placeLongitude;
}

public void setPlaceLongitude(final double placeLongitude) {
    this.placeLongitude = placeLongitude;
}

public double getPlaceLatitude() {
    return placeLatitude;
}

public void setPlaceLatitude(final double placeLatitude) {
    this.placeLatitude = placeLatitude;
}
}
```

Next you will need a XML parser class to retrieve XML data to Place type list. You can use the following sample: **PlaceXmlParser.class**

```
public class PlaceXmlParser {
private static final String TAG = PlaceXmlParser.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String PLACE_ID = "place_id";
private static final String PLACE_NAME = "name";
private static final String PLACE_DESCRIPTION = "description";
private static final String PLACE_COORDINATES = "coordinates";

public PlaceXmlParser() {
    super();
}

public List<Place> parsePlacesXml(final InputStream xmlStream) {
    Place place = null;
    final List<Place> placeList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        final XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        final XmlPullParser parser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();
        parser.setInput(xmlStream, null);
        int event = parser.getEventType();
        while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (event == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                final String name = parser.getName();
                switch (name) {
                    case PLACE_ID:
                        place = new Place();
                        setPlaceId(parser, place);
                        break;
                    case PLACE_NAME:
                        setPlaceName(parser, place);
                        break;
                    case PLACE_DESCRIPTION:
                        setPlaceDescription(parser, place);
                        break;
                    case PLACE_COORDINATES:
                        setPlaceLatLong(parser, place);
                        placeList.add(place);
                        break;
                }
            }
            event = parser.next();
        }
    } catch (final XmlPullParserException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }
    return placeList;
}

private boolean areValidArgs(final XmlPullParser parser, final Place place) {
    return null != parser && null != place;
}

private void setPlaceId(final XmlPullParser parser, final Place place) {
    if (areValidArgs(parser, place)) {
        final String placeId = getTagValue(parser);
        place.setPlaceId(Integer.parseInt(placeId));
    }
}

private void setPlaceName(final XmlPullParser parser, final Place place) {
    if (areValidArgs(parser, place)) {
        final String placeName = getTagValue(parser);
        place.setPlaceName(placeName);
    }
}

private void setPlaceDescription(final XmlPullParser parser, final Place place) {
    if (areValidArgs(parser, place)) {
        final String placeDescription = getTagValue(parser);
        place.setPlaceDescription(placeDescription);
    }
}

private void setPlaceLatLong(final XmlPullParser parser, final Place place) {
    if (areValidArgs(parser, place)) {
        final String[] latLong = getTagValue(parser).split(";");
        if (3 == latLong.length) {
            place.setPlaceLatitude(Double.parseDouble(latLong[1]));
            place.setPlaceLongitude(Double.parseDouble(latLong[2]));
        }
    }
}

private String getTagValue(final XmlPullParser parser) {
    String result = "";
    try {
        if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            result = parser.getText();
            parser.nextTag();
        }
    } catch (final XmlPullParserException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }
    return result;
}

}
```

Finally, in you Google Map's activity, implement OnMapReadyCallback interface, override onMapReady method and add place markers to Google Map: **MapActivity.class**

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private GoogleMap mMap;
private List<Place> placeList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    this.placeList = getPlaceList();
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    this.mMap = googleMap;
    addPlaceListMarkersToGoogleMap();
}

private void addPlaceListMarkersToGoogleMap() {
    for (final Place place : this.placeList) {
        final LatLong latLong = new LatLong(place.getPlaceLatitude(), place.getPlaceLongitude());
        this.mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLong).title(place.getPlaceName()));
    }
}

private List<Place> getPlaceList() {
    final String xmlString = "<placesp>" +
            "<placep>" +
            "  <place_id>1</place_id>" +
            "  <name>Place1</name>" +
            "  <description>Place description 1</description>" +
            "  <coordinates>;40.430224;21.559570</coordinates>" +
            "</placep>" +
            "<placep>" +
            "  <place_id>2</place_id>" +
            "  <name>Place2</name>" +
            "  <description>Place description 2</description>" +
            "  <coordinates>;40.423324;21.062439</coordinates>" +
            "</placep>" +
            "<placep>" +
            "  <place_id>3</place_id>" +
            "  <name>Place3</name>" +
            "  <description>Place description 3</description>" +
            "  <coordinates>;40.266952;21.238220</coordinates>" +
            "</placep>" +
            "</placesp>";
    final InputStream xmlStream = getXmlStream(xmlString);
    final PlaceXmlParser parser = new PlaceXmlParser();
    return parser.parsePlacesXml(xmlStream);
}

private InputStream getXmlStream(final String xmlString) {
    InputStream xmlStream = null;
    try {
        xmlStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (final UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return xmlStream;
}
}
```

Provided code works well for given XML sample, be aware of possible exceptions and handle it. Hope this help!

Comment: hey thank you so much for the time you took to answer this! I am trying to implement this on my project and I have a question, maybe a stupid one. On the code for MapActivity.class you write `final String xmlString = "<placesp>" + "<placep>" + "  <place_id>1</place_id>" + ..;` etc. Why this? Cant I somehow plugin the **placesp.xml** file there? So if the file's content change the map would show different markers?

Comment: First, yes, you can read data from an XML file instead of from hardcoded string and the example provided works as well. Second, yes, if you change the file content (the information not the format) the map would show different markers

Comment: How could I do this? Should I put the name of the xml file instead of the harcoded string? Something like ..="placesp.xml"? Or I need more code that that?

Comment: I provided you an excellent answer, which works really well. You do not validate my answer and you want that I continue doing your work?

Comment: whats up with the attitude? I asked the question because I wanted to know how can I take the data from the xml file and show them to a map. what I ask you in the comments of your answer is what I wanted to know by asking the question. I know how to show a place on a map, what I dont know is how to take the data from an xml file and then show them to the map. So, though your answer may work really well, it doesnt answer my question. Again thanks for your time.