# How to create and write custom resource value xml in android programmatically

Tags: android, android-resources

I am making an application which can be configured on the fly via backend. For that I have a feature flag api that returns a set of boolean flags that indicates certain features are enabled or disabled. How do I create an custom bools.xml file in res/value directory for this.

Comment: I think you should have your answer [Hear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152933/android-how-to-add-a-custom-xml-file-in-res-values-and-how-to-register-the-custo), Hope this helps you.

Comment: I think you need to go for a storage , You can use SQLite or SharedPreference to store the values and than perform action based on them.

Comment: @HectorMorris It explains about accessing the already created resource file items. I want to know how can I create a custom resource file and store values in it.

Comment: @PiashSarker I know sqlite or shared preferences can be used. But If we use resource file, it can be easily accessed R.resname than hitting database every time.

Comment: The best way to make it done is you can use local Data Storage,What i mean to says is that you can make your own file With the File Operations and have it on the Res folder.User EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: You cannot alter values of resource files once they are compiled and added in apk package. You have to rely on some storage like sharedpreference / db. If you want to avoid those overheads take a look at Firebase's Remote config library here https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/